# How can I test on other images in this supervised image processing method?

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm trying to implement the code given in the link here: [Java Image Processing](http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/7020-tutorial-supervisedclassification.jsp#tutorialsabrieftutorialonsupervisedimageclassification). It provides a method to identify the amount of land, sea, pastures, cloudy area and so on. They have three files as input:

1: The `image.png` to be processed

2: A `classes.txt` file describing the colors of different classifications like land and sea

3: A `samples.txt`file showing the divisions of land, water, urban areas within the image by it's rectangular area specified in pixels.

I understand that `samples.txt` file is unique for each image and the code classifies based on that but is there any way I can use the `samples.txt` and `image.png` of one image for training to test on another image say `image2.png`? Here's the code where the divisions are printed in a file:

```
for(int row=0;row<=h;row++)
                    for(int col=0;col<=w;col++)
                    {
                        int rgb = input.getRGB(x+col,y+row);
                        int r = (int)((rgb&0x00FF0000)>>>16); // Red level
                        int g = (int)((rgb&0x0000FF00)>>>8);  // Green level
                        int b = (int) (rgb&0x000000FF);       // Blue level
                        // Use those values to adjust the bounds for the parallelepipeds.
                        min[0] = Math.min(min[0],r);  max[0] = Math.max(max[0],r);
                        min[1] = Math.min(min[1],g);  max[1] = Math.max(max[1],g);
                        min[2] = Math.min(min[2],b);  max[2] = Math.max(max[2],b);
                    }
```

The `input` here is the image file. How can I divide this code as to train with the `input` image and test on another image?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just take a look at the part where they create the new image with class colours.

Do the same with any other image. Get any pixel's value, determin which class it belongs to and paint it into an output image using the class colour.

Of course your second image has to look like the one you used to teach the classifier with. Otherwise you won't get good results.

Comment: Thanks a million for the answer. I tried but couldn't make that happen clearly. Could you possibly help me a little with a sample of a code or just words in to specifically the part I should change?